# I have a gradle build script and want to write a task to checkout a remote git repository. What will be the plugin and the task used to do it?

Tags: git, gradle, build.gradle, bitbucket

Trying to write a gradle git checkout task. Don't know which plugin is used for git in gradle and how to write the checkout task.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `project.tasks.create` directive, as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35515187/6309), although I would now use [git switch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) instead of checkout.

Or you can use [`grgit/grgit-gradle`](http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/grgit-gradle.html), which uses [GrGit](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit) (and that includes [checkout](http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/grgit-checkout.html))